# How to unset adminmenu completely?

Tags: admin-menu

Is there a way to completely remove (unset) the left hand side admin menu? I examined the ozh-admin-drop-down-menu plugin, since it removes the entire admin menu and adds a top menu bar in order to get a clue.. I made a few snippets, but probably I am missing sth.. I couldn't manage  to find a way out..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just to explain the solution better:

I made below additions to theme's function.php in order to remove visually (hide) left hand admin menu:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'add_custom_admin_style'); 
function add_custom_admin_style(){
    wp_register_style('custom_admin_style', content_url('themes').'/custom_admin.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('custom_admin_style');
}
```

And then I created custom_admin.css file in themes folder and put below lines:

```
#adminmenuwrap, #adminmenuback {display:none;}
#wpcontent, #footer {margin-left: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can remove it globally, maybe with traversing the global `$menu` array.

But you can unset each individually:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'Wps_remove_tools', 99 );
function Wps_remove_tools(){

remove_menu_page( 'index.php' );                     //dashboard
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php' );                      //posts
remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );                    //media
remove_menu_page( 'link-manager.php' );              //links
remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=page' );       //page
remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );             //comments
remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );                    //appearance
remove_menu_page( 'plugins.php' );                   //plugins
remove_menu_page( 'users.php' );                     //users
remove_menu_page( 'tools.php' );                     //tools
remove_menu_page( 'options-general.php' );           //settings
```

}

Comment: Thank you.. but this removes only the menu items and leaves an empty gray bar..

Comment: You can just hide it with css then.... `#adminmenuwrap{display:none;}`

Comment: ok, that was the last option.. :) together with #adminmenuback{display:none;} and #wpcontent {margin-left: 15px;}, the admin bar is being removed visually and the remaining part of the page spans the area emptied by the admin bar. As far as I can understand there is no way to stop construction of the original menu.. Thank you for the ideas Wyck :)